# Gradle - spring-security-taglibs:4.0.4.RELEASE is internally downloading spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, gradle

In my project, I having `spring-jdbc:4.1.4.RELEASE` which is working fine with no issues. Now for a new change I am trying to add `spring-security-taglibs:4.0.4.RELEASE` in my project, which is trying to download `spring-security-taglibs:4.0.4.RELEASE` and `spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE`, which will cause severe issue in my project. Because what `spring-jdbc` version required for me is `4.1.4.RELEASE` which I specified explicitly. How can I avoid this? What is happening behind?

This is weird behavior from gradle

Comment: Add your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have something like this in your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:4.0.4.RELEASE'
}
```

So this introduces a conflict in your dependencies which is visible in the output of the following task:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.springframework:spring-jdbc

:dependencyInsight
org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.5.RELEASE (conflict resolution)
\--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:4.0.4.RELEASE
     \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:4.0.4.RELEASE
          \--- compile

org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.4.RELEASE -> 4.2.5.RELEASE
\--- compile
```

The arrow above (->) means that gradle default resolution strategy was used and 4.2.5 (newest) was chosen by gradle. You can read in gradle docs:

> Gradle offers the following conflict resolution strategies:
>
> Newest: The newest version of the dependency is used. This is Gradle's default strategy, and is often an appropriate choice as long
>   as versions are backwards-compatible.
>
> Fail: A version conflict results in a build failure. This strategy requires all version conflicts to be resolved explicitly in the build
>   script.

[Link.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dependency_management_and_java)

What I see as options for you:

- use the newest `spring-jdbc` (the best IMO)
- use older spring security taglibs which dependes on older `spring-jdbc`
- resolve the version conflict within your scripts (the worst IMO) and keep your fingers crossed. You will need at least some luck :-) Details - [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)

Comment: Yes, I am using now the older spring-security version